# System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type Android App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I developed a Xamarin Cross Platform application that is working perfectly on Windows but when I try to run in Android I get the following error:

*System.InvalidOperationException: 'There was an error reflecting type 'Producao.GetSeccoesResponseGetSeccoesResult'.'*

I have a webservice connected to the application and this error is triggered when I run a method that returns a datatable (wsProducao.GetSeccoes):

```
 void CarregaSeccoes()
    {

        List<SeccaoCentro> Seccoes = new List<SeccaoCentro>();

        var a = wsProducao.GetSeccoes(Application.Current.Properties["TipoPlataforma"] as string, Application.Current.Properties["Empresa"] as string, Application.Current.Properties["Utilizador"] as string, Application.Current.Properties["Password"] as string);

        if (a.Any1.HasChildNodes != false)
        {
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(a.Any1.InnerXml);

            XmlNodeList xNodeList = xml.SelectNodes("/DocumentElement /Seccoes");
            foreach (XmlNode xNode in xNodeList)
            {

                Seccoes.Add(new SeccaoCentro()
                {

                    IDSeccao = Convert.ToInt32(xNode["IDSeccao"].InnerText),
                    Seccao = xNode["Seccao"].InnerText,
                    Descricao = xNode["Seccao"].InnerText.ToUpper() +  " - " + xNode["Descricao"].InnerText.ToUpper()

                });

            }

            cvSeccoes.ItemsSource = Seccoes;

        }

        else
        {
            cvSeccoes.ItemsSource = null;
        }
    }
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Which line of code does this problem occur?  Could you please post the full error log about this problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT thie error occur in var a = wsProducao.GetSeccoes(Application.Current.Properties["TipoPlataforma"] as string, Application.Current.Properties["Empresa"] as string, Application.Current.Properties["Utilizador"] as string, Application.Current.Properties["Password"] as string);